# Unconfirmed Transaction, what can I do?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, revert-transaction

I sent a small amount of bitcoins from my electrum wallet. I control both addresses either side.

the transaction can be viewed here

https://blockchain.info/tx/a80f1ef7e4f2fdda8ca3fe2948bbad6a316976e9d91a6deacd56d3346f76d652

It's been unconfirmed for around 16 hours now, what can I do about this and how I do get my bitcoins back?

Answer (score 0):

Please wait. the estimated transaction time is [3d days](https://www.blockonomics.co/api/tx?txid=a80f1ef7e4f2fdda8ca3fe2948bbad6a316976e9d91a6deacd56d3346f76d652). The tx will be either confirmed or will be removed from mempool. If you have opted in for [RBF](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1663486.0) , you can increase the fee.